# Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined -> Meteor + Nodejs + Trying to run bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to add the bcryptjs package and use it in my Meteor app.

I have installed bcrypt via `meteor npm install --save bcrypt` and it went okay.

I use `import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';` to start using bcrypt functions.

However, I run into this problem where the console log throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined
at modules.js?hash=0a5b088c5613f9a01f50dd13461d2cc4ca666b66:35733
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (modules.js?hash=0a5b088c5613f9a01f50dd13461d2cc4ca666b66:35732)
at log.js (modules.js?hash=0a5b088c5613f9a01f50dd13461d2cc4ca666b66:29972)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343)
at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238)
at node-pre-gyp.js (modules.js?hash=0a5b088c5613f9a01f50dd13461d2cc4ca666b66:27190)
at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:343)
at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=8587d188e038b75ecd27ed2469a52b269e38fb62:238)
at bcrypt.js (modules.js?hash=0a5b088c5613f9a01f50dd13461d2cc4ca666b66:26761)
```

After digging a bit, it appears that the `set-blocking` node package was throwing this error (there was no `stream` while the package uses `stream._handle`).

I couldn't find any specific answer w.r.t a Meteor context here on SO.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution you got for this ?

Comment: @YogeshwarTanwar sorry, I've since moved over to Vuejs and did not work with Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bcryptjs` instead.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

You probably have an unusual server configuration that has busted your ability to use `bcrypt` the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because you are loading `bcrypt` library on the client.

Import bcrypt library only in the files that are run in meteor server.